# "Take out" or "take away" for removing from a collection?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, british-english

What preposition do I have to use in this sentence?

> If you have ten candies and take **out/away** six, you are left with four.

I think "out" is right. The dictionary phrases *take [something] out* or *take away* under [take](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/take) don't really help here.

Comment: Although I've improved this question, I've left something for you [to add](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/451625/edit), Ines. You need to explain why the dictionary definitions don't really help.

Comment: I would say "take away".  But "If you have ten candies in a box, and take out six, you are left with four."  Since taking them out of a box is sensible... Just as taking them away from me is sensible.

Comment: I don't know Andrew, what about take up?             I don't really think it can be the answer

Comment: *Away* is normal. Anything else would require some weird context to set it up.  It leaves the focus of the sentence on the ones that remain. If there are ten candies and I take out six,  I have six of them. *Take out* tends to have the focus follow the ones that are taken.

Comment: 'Take out' presupposes a container, not mentioned here (and the container metaphor is messy here). But note that if you have ten sweets in a packet and take out six, you are left with ten (four still in the packet).

Comment: I have just found the answer it is "away" thank you so much❤️

Comment: You could always just use **remove** and bypass any controversy. ;)

Comment: I'll just  mention as you have tagged this British English we don't use the term "candies" we call them "sweets".